# JS Globalize - load json cldr

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, cldr

I have a problem with the latest version of `globalize.js`.
To work with it I had to load the `cldr modules` and language definitions.

Now I had this example from the globalize docs:

```
// loading needed modules
$.get('/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json', Globalize.load);
$.get('/Scripts/cldr/main/en/numbers.json', Globalize.load);
$.get('/Scripts/cldr/main/de/numbers.json', Globalize.load);

// set current language
lobalize.locale('de-de');
```

My problem now is that the local json files are loaded async. That means at the moment where my script is try to set the current language, the modules are not yet loaded.

Now I tried to be smart and made this:

```
$.get('/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json', function (data) {
        Globalize.load(data);
        Globalize.locale('de-de');
});

$.get('/Scripts/cldr/main/en/numbers.json', Globalize.load);
$.get('/Scripts/cldr/main/de/numbers.json', Globalize.load);
```

This will work until I really used globalize format methode.
Inside my HTML I use globalize inside a knockout binding like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: Globalize.formatNumber(SomeNumber, { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })"></span>
```

Now the "formatNumber" method is throwing an error because not all module are loaded at the moment the binding is happend.

My question is now, how can I sync up my JavaScript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually 2 ways to solve the issue:

1. Use `$.ajax` with `async: false` option to load your json modules.
2. Use [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to have a single callback on all your ajax requests.

**1. Using `async: false`**

You can use more general method `$.ajax` instead of `$.get` (see [description](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). It has `async` option:

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.

So you can rewrite your requests as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        Globalize.load(data);
    }
});
```

You do this for all 3 of your requests and then call:

```
// set current language
lobalize.locale('de-de');
```

Just like you did before. But now, since all requests are done synchronously, this code should work as expected. The downside of this solution is that it has synchronous requests which will cause some delays. That is why I suggest you the second option:

**2. Using deferreds:**
You can use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function to combine success callbacks of all three requests to one like this:

```
$.when($.get('/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json'), 
       $.get('/Scripts/cldr/main/en/numbers.json'), 
       $.get('/Scripts/cldr/main/de/numbers.json'))
.done(function(result1, result2, result3) {
    Globalize.load(result1[0]); //contains data of first executed request
    Globalize.load(result2[0]); //contains data of second executed request
    Globalize.load(result3[0]); //contains data of third executed request
    // set current language
    lobalize.locale('de-de');
    // here you should fire your knockout binding
});
```

The good thing is that all requests are now done asynchronously. But this would still not solve your knockout binding issue. To resolve it, `ko.applyBindings` should also be called in success callback, when all data is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the when function. I think I has now to build some general "Init" function because I dont want to insert this code on every vie page. So i think best way is to put it into the layout page and call some "viewinit" function that is inside the view page. Puh this was much more easy on the older globalize Version.

Comment: @SteffenMangold, you're welcome! If you used either of approaches, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Thank you so much, @IlyaLuzyanin! This helped so much. Now I just need to figure out how to load my external and inline scripts inside of the done function as well, as those have dependencies on Globalize being loaded....